Agda proof that a type is a set dont work anymore with cubical agda
So I'm implementing some (most of) HoTT definitions in Agda. For checking that a type is a set I have defined:
isSet : ∀ (A : Set) → Set
isSet A = ∀ {x y : A} (p q : (x ≡ y)) → (p ≡ q)

This proof that Σ(x :a) P x is a set (when the P x's are) works perfectly fine in "normal" (without importing cubical) agda:
Σ-isSet : ∀ {A : Set} (P : A → Set) → (∀ (x : A) → isSet (P x)) → isSet (∃[ z ] (P z))
Σ-isSet {A} P φ {x} {y} refl refl = refl

But when I import cubical agda (Because I need it for defining HIT), the proof doesn't work anymore:
Cannot split on argument of non-datatype x ≡ y
when checking that the pattern refl has type x ≡ y

What's happening? Is the proof incorrect, or do I need to use different operators when using cubical agda? Thank you!

The first issue is that your proof relies on axiom K and does not type-check --without-K. Axiom K essentially says that every type is a set, so it's no surprise that your lemma is trivial in that setting (notice that your proof doesn't even use the assumption φ!). Axiom K is incompatible with univalence and is therefore not assumed in HoTT.
In fact, your lemma is false in HoTT: you need both A to be a set and P to be a family of sets to conclude that Σ A P is a set. This is a good exercise: give an example of a type A and a family of sets P : A → Type such that Σ A P is not a set.
The second issue is that cubical Agda uses path types instead of inductive identity types, so you cannot pattern match on refl. Paths in A are essentially functions out of the interval type I → A with specified values at the endpoints i0 and i1. Path types support mostly the same elimination principle as the one provided by pattern matching on refl (--without-K) in the form of J, but its computation rule on refl only holds up to another path instead of definitionally.
In cubical Agda, one usually proves the more general result that Σ preserves h-levels: if A is an n-type and P is a family of n-types then Σ A P is an n-type. See 1lab or cubical for example.

As a side note, you can rename Set to Type when working with HoTT to avoid confusion:
{-# OPTIONS --no-import-sorts #-}
open import Agda.Primitive renaming (Set to Type; Setω to Typeω)

This is done for you in most cubical/HoTT libraries.

Hi, thank you. I didnt even know of the existence of axiom K. I knew my proof was wrong but I didnt know what was wrong about it. Do you recommend any library for using only the HoTT part and not the cubical part? Im only interested in HoTT.

In that case you can have a look at agda-unimath, or Martín Escardó's HoTT/UF lecture notes and TypeTopology library.

Is Vanilla agda + "--without-K" enough to develop HoTT and work with HITs, or do I still need more stuff? I want to use a framework where Im unable to prove theorems that are false in HoTT. I also need to define HITs.

--without-K is supposed to be enough to make Agda consistent with HITs and univalence (save for bugs), but you still have to postulate those as axioms (see e.g. the circle in agda-unimath), whereas in cubical you can define them and compute with them.

Thanks, I dont know what I would do without you ^^
